# Email confirmation in Web API

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

I have Web API application and I want to implement email confirmation.

Now I have method that takes `address` -- the client host which will be in callback url `uriBuilder` and will be opened by the user from mail:

```
public async Task<IdentityResult> RegisterAsync(string email, string userName, string password, string address)
{
    var user = new ApplicationUser { Email = email, UserName = userName };
    var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, password);

    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
        var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);

        var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(address) { Port = -1 };
        var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uriBuilder.Query);
        query["userId"] = user.Id;
        query["code"] = code;
        uriBuilder.Query = query.ToString();

        await _emailService.SendEmailAsync
        (
            user.Email,
            "Email confirmation",
            $"Confirm the registration by clicking on the <a href='{uriBuilder}'>link</a>."
        );
    }

    return result;
}
```

Then on the client side will be POST call to the API:

```
public async Task<bool> ConfirmEmailAsync(string userId, string code)
{
    var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);

    if (user == null)
    {
        throw new UserNotFoundException();
    }

    var result = await _userManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(user, code);
    return result.Succeeded;
}
```

This is so that user do not interact with API directly.

Is it ok to pass the host address in the request? If not, what should I do if there are several clients? In case of one client I can move it to config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeap, it is ok to pass the host as parameter in the request.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose a user should be in your scenario associated with specific host/address. You can store in the Db the host associated with the user and get that on the RegisterAsync method.

Comment: What about case when user uses more than one client?

Comment: If that is the case/scenario, it is an option to pass the host as parameter in the request.